# how to get Category values from json in android?

Tags: android, arrays, json

{
    "response": 
{
    "Category": 
        [
            "Restaurant",
            "Salon",
            "Spa",
            "Dry Cleaners",
            "Car Spa",
            "Hospitals"
        ]
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it can be Pseudo Code

```
 String json = <YourJSon String>
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("Category");

    for(int i =0; i<array.size();i++){
    String s = array.get(i).getString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this-

```
     try {
            String json = <Your Json String>;
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray category = response.getJSONArray("Category");
            for (int i = 0; i < category.length(); i++) {
                Log.d("categories are", category.getString(i));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```